# Anonymous Crypto method error: last block incomplete in decryption

Tags: apex, crypto

I am testing some Crypto methods for decryption in the anonymous window. But getting this error while trying with valid inputs:

```
Blob key = Blob.valueOf('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
System.debug('key: ' +key);
Blob encodedEncryptedBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode('SOME ENCRYPTED VALUE');
System.debug('encodedEncryptedBlob: ' +encodedEncryptedBlob);
Blob decryptedData = Crypto.decryptWithManagedIV('AES128', key, encodedEncryptedBlob);
String decryptedDataString = decryptedData.toString();
System.debug('decryptedDataString: ' +decryptedDataString);
```

Error message:

> FATAL_ERROR System.SecurityException: last block incomplete in decryption

What could be my mistake here?

**Note**: I have received those key and encrypted data from our partner, so that data is valid.

Comment: You're missing the IV, so the data is the wrong length. That's the usual cause for this error. Check with the data provider to see what the IV should be, and use the normal decrypt method instead of decryptWithManagedIV.

Comment: @sfdcfox Sure, I will try to get the IV (initialization vector) from our provider. I'll keep you posted.

Comment: @sfdcfox can you please elaborate, what's wrong with using decryptWithManagedIV() ?

Comment: @wintermute the decryptWithManagedIV method is used with encryptWithManagedIV; this prefixes the payload with the IV used. In this case, the IV was not included in the payload, so it had to be acquired from the vendor.